# How to get a *.cer file to add a self-signed HTTPS certificate in command

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

It is related to the this question:
[How to get a *.cer file to add a self-signed HTTPS certificate as trusted for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442758/how-to-get-a-cer-file-to-add-a-self-signed-https-certificate-as-trusted-for-ja)

As mentioned in the answer:

```
With firefox is is done by double-clicking on the lock in the status bar, clicking on the button "View certificate", then in the "Details" tab, click on "Export..."
```

I am wondering if there is anyway to get the .cer file in command, so that I can get the process automated?

Comment: Let me see, I think you want to extract the `cer` file automatically (by running a command) from a HTTPS URL? That means you want to connect (in some way) to a HTTPS endpoint and retrieve the certificate of that server? (all by running a command) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interact with a server over SSL, one of the well known tools is `OpenSSL`. You can install it easily on your Linux or Windows. The OpenSSL has commands which could be used to retrieve SSL certificate of a server.

Take a look at the below post for step by step tutorial on retrieving server certificate through OpenSSL (pay special attention to comments in order to automate the overall process)

[Quickpost: Retrieving an SSL Certificate](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2007/12/23/quickpost-retrieving-an-ssl-certificate/)